# Array conversion using scikit-image: from integer to float

Tags: numpy, type-conversion, scikit-image

I am facing some kind of problem when converting an integer image to a float image using scikit-image.

This is an example (the image is a 2 pixel image):

```
from numpy import array,uint8;
import skimage;

rgb = array([array([[0,0,0],[0,0,5]])]) 
i1 = skimage.img_as_float(rgb)#rgb.dtype ->dtype('int32')
i2 = skimage.img_as_float(rgb.astype(uint8))
i3 = skimage.img_as_float(rgb.astype(float))

print i1[0,1,:]
print i2[0,1,:]
print i3[0,1,:]
```

I expected this:

```
[ 0.  0.  5.]
[ 0.  0.  5.]
[ 0.  0.  5.]
```

But I got this:

```
[  2.32830644e-10   2.32830644e-10   2.56113708e-09]
[ 0.          0.          0.01960784]
[ 0.  0.  5.]
```

It is normal to loss precision from `float` to `int`, but here I am losing the real information when passing from `int` to `float` using `img_as_float`. I didn't found anything when reading the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/9a5a767ce87b6e203530315bac3501f35c1f5fb4/skimage/util/dtype.py)...

Why is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`img_as_float()` is not just type conversion, it convert full unsigned integer range to [0, 1], full signed integer range to [-1, 1].

- i1, the dtype is int32, means convert [-2147483648, 2147483647] to [-1, 1]
- i2, the dtype is uint8, means convert [0, 255] to [0, 1]
- i3, because the dtype is already float, do nothing.