# RGB to XYZ in Scikit-Image

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, colors, scikit-image

I am trying to convert an image from RGB to XYZ using scikit-image. I found out that there are some differences depending the input type:

```
from numpy import array,uint8
import skimage.color

rgb = array([array([[56,79,132],[255,100,70]])]) 
i1 = skimage.color.rgb2xyz(rgb)#rgb.dtype ->dtype('int32')
i2 = skimage.color.rgb2xyz(rgb.astype(uint8))
i3 = skimage.color.rgb2xyz(rgb.astype(float))

print i1[0,1,:]
print i2[0,1,:]
print i3[0,1,:]
```

This is the output:

```
[  5.55183419e-09   4.73226247e-09   3.02426596e-09]
[ 0.46907236  0.3082294   0.09272133]
[ 240644.54537677  153080.21825017   39214.47581034]
```

The cause of the differences is the function `img_to_float` which is used inside `rgb2xyz` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429261/array-conversion-using-scikit-image-from-integer-to-float)).

But I am wondering: What is the correct way to use `rgb2xyz`?

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764744/why-is-there-such-a-difference-between-rgb-to-xyz-color-conversions) there are multiple solutions, depending on the formula, but again: what is the correct image type that is **required** by `rgb2xyz`? It seems that `unit8`, but why? Thanks!

Comment: There is a reference that helps to understand this: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/user_guide/data_types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be self explanatory, but floating point values should have a range in `(0, 1)`, and integer type have their full range mapped to `(0, 1)` (for unsigned types) or `(-1, 1)` (for signed types):

```
>>> from numpy import int32
>>> skimage.color.rgb2xyz((rgb / 255 * (2**31 - 1)).astype(int32))
array([[[ 0.08590003,  0.08097913,  0.2293394 ],
        [ 0.46907236,  0.3082294 ,  0.09272133]]])
>>> skimage.color.rgb2xyz(rgb.astype(uint8))
array([[[ 0.08590003,  0.08097913,  0.2293394 ],
        [ 0.46907236,  0.3082294 ,  0.09272133]]])
>>> skimage.color.rgb2xyz(rgb.astype(float) / 255)
array([[[ 0.08590003,  0.08097913,  0.2293394 ],
        [ 0.46907236,  0.3082294 ,  0.09272133]]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaime! So you are suggesting that the correct use of `rgb2xyz` is having the input scaled to the correct range, aren't you?

Comment: Well, the normal usage would be to have everything be `np.uint8` with the usual 0-255 range. If you switch to floats, remember to divide by 255. And don't use other int type unless you know what (and why) you are doing...

Comment: No need to do any manual scaling if you use the appropriate tools: ``img_as_float``, ``img_as_ubyte``, etc.